# AWS SDK generates wrong presigned url for reading an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, signed-url

I am using S3 to store videos.
And now, I am using presigned urls to restrict access to them.
I am using these functions to generate the presigned url:

```
var getVideoReadSignedUrl = async function (url) {
  const key = awsS3Helpers.parseVideoKeyFromVideoUrl(url);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl(
      "getObject",
      {
        Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
        Expires: 300,
      },
      (err, url) => {
        console.log(
          " ~ file: s3-config.js ~ line 77 ~ returnnewPromise ~ err",
          err
        );
        console.log(
          " ~ file: s3-config.js ~ line 77 ~ returnnewPromise ~ url",
          url
        );
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(url);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

And this:

```
const parseVideoKeyFromVideoUrl = (object_url) => {
  const string_to_remove =
    "https://" + AWS_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3." + REGION + ".amazonaws.com/";
  const object_key = object_url.replace(string_to_remove, "");
  return object_key;
};
```

This is an example of a video url:

> https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%2F60e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4

So I call `getVideoReadSignedUrl` to get the signed url to give access to it:

```
getVideoReadSignedUrl(
  "https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%2F60e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4"
);
```

`parseVideoKeyFromVideoUrl` correctly parses the key from the url:

```
videos%2F60e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4
```

**BUT**, this is what `getVideoReadSignedUrl` generates:

> https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%252F60e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-xxx-xxxxx&X-Amz-Credential=AKIARxxxxxMVEWKUW%2F20221120%2Feu-xxxx-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221120xxxx19Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=0203efcfaxxxxxxc53815746f75a357ff9d53fe581491d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

When I open that url in the browser it tells me that the **key does not exist**:

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>videos%2F60e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4</Key>
```

Even though in the **error message** the key is the same as in the **original url**.
But, I noticed a slight difference in the key between the original url and the presigned url:
Key in original url:

> videos% |2F60| e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4

Key in signed url:

> videos% |252F60| e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4

Not sure if this is causing the issue.

---

**NOTE:**
For the upload, I am using multipart upload and the reason the video url is structured like that is because of `file_name` here:

```
const completeMultiPartUpload = async (user_id, parts, upload_id) => {
  let file_name;
  file_name = `videos/${user_id}.mp4`;
  let params = {
    Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: file_name,
    MultipartUpload: {
      Parts: parts,
    },
    UploadId: upload_id,
  };

  return data;
};
```

However, it should be stored like this:

> /videos/e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4

and not like this:

> /videos%2F60e589xxxxxxxxx463c.mp4

I am not sure why it replaces **/** with **%2F60** and this may be what's causing the whole issue.

---

After more investigation, I found that `completeMultiPartUpload` returns this:

```
{
          Location:
            "https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4",
          Bucket: "lodeep-storage-3",
          Key: "videos/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4",
          ETag: '"ee6xxxxxxxxxxxxf11-1"',
        }
```

And so the actualy object key is saved like this in S3:

```
"videos/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4"
```

And this is the object url if I get it from AWS console:

> https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4

But, in the database, this url gets saved like this since it's what `completeMultiPartUpload` function finally returns:

> https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4

Notice how **/** is replaced with **%2F**.

So, when I am generating the signed url to read the video, the function that parses the key from the url `parseVideoKeyFromVideoUrl`, instead of getting the correct url in the S3:

> https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4
> It gets the one stored in the database:
> https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4

And so instead of returning this as a key:

> /videos/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4

It returns this:

> /videos%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4

Which is an incorrect key. And so the signed url to read the video is incorrect. And I get this key doesn't exist error.

Comment: Isn't it possible to run the returned key through a URL decoder function which would give you the correct name?

Comment: `parseVideoKeyFromVideoUrl ` is not parsing the URL correctly.  It should be URL decoding the resulting key.

Comment: I tried  `decodeURI(
    "https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/videos%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4"
  )` but it did not remove the %2F. It returned the URI as it is.

Comment: But, using this online decoder, it actually worked https://www.urldecoder.org/ and it returned the original url

Comment: Actually using this decodeURIComponent worked. Because it works on special characters such as / . Thank you guys for the tips!